# Why does this core.async channel hang unpredictably?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async

This is a portion of a script that I'm trying to use with channels from `core.async`. Around half the time that I run it, it will stop without completing and moving on through the program; other times, it completes successfully.

I suspect that the issue is related to the way that I'm waiting (with `(<!! commchan)`) for a response from the async thread -- but how should I handle this instead?

```
(defn async-writer
  [chan num-buckets]
  (let [file-handles (get-filehandles num-buckets)]
    (ca/thread (loop []
                 (when-let [rec (<!! chan)]
                   (.write (file-handles (record->bucket rec num-buckets))
                           (str (rec :rows) \newline))
                   (recur)))
               :finished)))

(defn process-data-files
  [data-directory num-buckets]
  (let [outchan (ca/chan)
        commchan (async-writer outchan num-buckets)]
    (try
      (doseq [f (data-files data-directory)]
        (let [rdr (registered-file clojure.java.io/reader f)]
          (doseq [r (do (println "Processing" (. f getName))
                        (file->records rdr))]
            (put! outchan r))
          (close-file rdr)))
      (close! outchan)
      prefix
      (finally (<!! commchan)
               (close-all-open-files)))))
```

Comment: How many data-files are you processing? Your outchan is unbuffered and by default a maximum of 1024 pending puts is allowed.

Comment: Hmm. I'm definitely processing enough that if the writer got behind there are 1024 puts that could back up.  How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I used Igrapenthin's comment to solve the issue. I added a buffer to my channels and changed the asynchronous `put!` calls to `>!!` calls. This way, when the buffer is full, the main thread waits for the asynchronous writers.

Comment: If you don't want to block the main-thread, use `go` and `>!` or another `thread`. Buffering shouldn't be necessary as you are only putting from one place.